# specifying div id with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have buttons and divs and in each part I have them with the same ID I want to get the ID of button and use it for refreshing the div html.how should I write the * section?

```
   $(function() {
         $(".button").click(function(){ 
         var id=$(this).attr('id');
         var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "download_number.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html)
           {
          *********I HAVE PROBLEM HERE**************
            $('how to get the id of the div from var id of button above?').html(html);
          } 
           });

         });
              });
```

Div:

```
  Downloaded:<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" ><?php echo $downloadcount;?></div>
```

Button:

```
 <input type = "button" value="Download" class="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="dl">
```

**If I get class It will update the whole divs I want to update just the div realted to the button**

Comment: Valid HTML doesn't reuse ID's... it would be better to do this as a class instead of an ID, elements can handle multiple classes.

Comment: if I get class it will update the whole divs but I want just update the div that is realated to that button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the id but prefix them then build the name up...

```
<div id="div_<?php echo $id; ?>" ><?php echo $downloadcount;?></div>
```

button:

```
<input type = "button" value="Download" class="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="dl">
```

Then in you're code you have the id used in the buttons already (and also it will be div_), so you can then in you're 'success' just do:

```
$("#div_"+id).html(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the same `id` on both the button and the div, `id` values **must** be unique in a document.

What I'd probably do is put the div's `id` on the button as a `data-divid` attribute (all attributes with the [prefix `data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) are valid on all elements as of HTML5, and harmless in earlier versions of HTML), like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" class="button" data-divid="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="dl">
```

Then change

```
var id=$(this).attr('id');
```

to

```
var id=$(this).attr('data-divid');
```

...and then use that `id` var in your `success` callback (as the callback is a closure created within the context where `id` is defined, and so the callback has access to `id`).

Here's a simple example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/arujiw/1) | [source](http://jsbin.com/arujiw/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">This is div1</div>
<div id="div2">This is div2</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" data-divid="div1" value="Update div1">
  <input type="button" data-divid="div2" value="Update div2">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-divid");

    // I'll use setTimeout to emulate doing an ajax call
    setTimeout(function() {
      // This is your 'success' function
      $("#" + id).html("Updated at " + new Date());
    }, 10);

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Just as a side note, you can use `.data()` to retrieve html5 `data-` attributes, these values are automatically pulled into the jQuery `data` object (as of `jQuery 1.4.3`)

Comment: @billyonecan: You can, but I don't recommend that you do. `data`'s use of `data-*` attributes is asymmetric and easily misunderstood. `data` only uses the `data-*` attribute values for initialization, after which there is **no** connection between `data` and the `data-*` attributes. Example of the confusion that can arise: http://jsbin.com/osekut/1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$('.button').attr('id');
```

to get the id of the button, then to change it:

```
$('.button').attr('id',''); //delete previous id if existing
$('.button').attr('id','yourNewId'); //set new id
```

then to use the new id:

```
$("#yourNewId").doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html to this:

```
Downloaded:<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="downloaded" ><?php echo $downloadcount;?></div>
```

then do something like:

```
var element_id = $(".downloaded").prop("id");
if(element_id = this.id){
   $("#"+element_id).html(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: see I have many divs I don't want to update the whole!!! I want to just update the div realted to the button

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(){ 
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "download_number.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $('.count-' + id).html(html); // for class
        } 
        });

    });
});
```

`<div class="count-<?php echo $id; ?>" ><?php echo $downloadcount;?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid using same IDS.
Then you can use CSS selectors:

```
$('div.class') //div
$('input[type="button"].youridclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the id attribute for that purpose, the id cannot be a number (valid html) and thereby id's needs to be unique. Use the data attrib instead.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, `ids` should be unique, you'll run into problems, particularly when using jQuery, if you have elements with the same `id`.

Without seeing your markup it's hard to give you a working example. But you can get the `id` of the `div` which corresponds to the clicked `button` by traversing the DOM.

Example markup:

```
<div id="example-div">
  <input type="button" value="Example" />
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent('div').prop('id'));
}); 

// outputs 'example-div'
```

Answer (score 0):

for your reference check the below link for the various ways that you can use to select the dom elements given the parent element.
jsperf.com/jquery-selectors-context/2